# ASP.NET MVC 5 DropDownList selectedindexchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

i wanna select one server and get only  databases name of server selected , but in this code .. gives me all databases of all server !! what is the solution please ?

Controller

```
List<SelectListItem> allServer = new List<SelectListItem>();
List<SelectListItem> alldatabases = new List<SelectListItem>();
allServer.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Please Select DataBase...", Value = "", Selected = true });
System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
System.Data.DataTable dt = instance.GetDataSources();
List<string> ddlInstances = new List<string>();      
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dr["InstanceName"]));
    ServerConnection Conn;
    Conn = new ServerConnection();
    Conn.ServerInstance = string.Concat(dr["ServerName"], "\\", dr["InstanceName"]);
    allServer.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = Conn.ServerInstance, Value = Conn.ServerInstance, Selected = true });   
    Server Ser = new Server(Conn);
    foreach (Database db in Ser.Databases)
    {
        alldatabases.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = db.Name, Value = db.Name, Selected = false });
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Connect", FormMethod.Get))
{
    Server Names
    @Html.DropDownList("SerNames")

    DB Names
    @Html.DropDownList("DBNames")
```

Comment: i wanna selected one server and get databases name of this server , but in this code , i get all databases of all server , what is the solution ?

Comment: Edit your question to explain the issue (not in comments)

Comment: your question not clear

Comment: this code show all server and all databases.., so i wanna selecte one servername of dropdownlist("serNames"), then i get only databases of this server selected in other dropdownlist("DBNames")

Answer (score 0):

This most be done with `javascript` and `ajax`, when the selected option in the server dropdown change make a call with `ajax` to an action in the controller that returns a `PartialView` with a dropdown populated with the list of databases for the selected server.

Answer (score 0):

Using the above your code, this will list out all the servers available because

```
System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance
```

Gets an instance of the System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator, which can        be used to retrieve information about available SQL Server instances.

So if you want have only one SQL Server Instance,  you must put some condition to get the one instance for iterating. For example"

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   if(!dr["InstanceName"]=="YourInstanceName"){ continue;} else {//Do you thing }
}
```